# Loop only checks one email

Tags: php

We get email adresses from a database of users. We then want to check these email adresses in a api and return number of breaches.

The problem is that now it seems like it only checks the first email adress. When we have more than one, the first gets the correct number of breaches, the second only gets 0.

```
<?php
ini_set("allow_url_fopen", 1);
include '/home/actiorwd/include/dbinfo.php';

$servername = "localhost";
$dbname = "actiorwd_websec";

// Create connection
$conn = new mysqli($servername, $user, $passw, $dbname);
// Check connection
if ($conn->connect_error) {
    die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);
}
//users contains two columns; email and breaches.
$sql = "SELECT * FROM users";
$result = $conn->query($sql);

$ch = curl_init();

if ($result->num_rows > 0) {
    // output data of each row

    while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
        $url = 'https://haveibeenpwned.com/api/v2/breachedaccount/';
        $url.= $row["email"];

        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
        curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_USERAGENT,'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows; U; Windows NT 5.1; en-US; rv:1.8.1.13) Gecko/20080311 Firefox/2.0.0.13');
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
        $results = curl_exec($ch);
        curl_close($ch);
        $obj = json_decode($results, TRUE);

        $usermail = $row["email"];



        $newbreaches = count($obj);

        //run if new breaches are found
        if($row["breaches"]!==$newbreaches){

          require_once('/home/actiorwd/public_html/PHPMailer/PHPMailerAutoload.php');
          $mail = new PHPMailer;

          $mail->isSMTP();                                      // Set mailer to use SMTP
          $mail->Host = 'cpanel40.proisp.no';  // Specify main and backup SMTP servers
          $mail->SMTPAuth = true;                               // Enable SMTP authentication
          $mail->Username = 'breached@actionscript.no';                 // SMTP username
          $mail->Password = 'PASSWORDHERE';                           // SMTP password
          $mail->SMTPSecure = 'ssl';                            // Enable TLS encryption, `ssl` also accepted
          $mail->Port = 465;                                    // TCP port to connect to

          $mail->setFrom('breached@actionscript.no', 'WebSec');
          $mail->addAddress($row["email"]);     // Add a recipient
          $mail->addReplyTo('breached@actionscript.no', 'WebSec');

          $mail->isHTML(true);                                  // Set email format to HTML

          $mail->Subject = 'Breached!!!!';
          $mail->Body    = 'Someone breached your account, there are: '.$newbreaches."breaches";
          $mail->AltBody = 'Someone breached your account in plain text';
          $mail->send();
          /*
          if(!$mail->send()) {
              echo 'Message could not be sent.';
              echo 'Mailer Error: ' . $mail->ErrorInfo;
          } else {
              echo 'Message has been sent';
          }

          */


          $updatebreach = "INSERT INTO users (`email`, `breaches`) VALUES ('$usermail', '$newbreaches') ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE `breaches` = '$newbreaches' ";
          //echo $updatebreach;

          if ($conn->query($updatebreach) === TRUE) {
              //echo "New record created successfully";
          } else {
              //echo "Error: " . $updatebreach . "<br>" . $conn->error;
          }


        }


    }
} else {
    echo "0 results";
}
$conn->close();
?>
```

Comment: Well, you need to do basic debugging. Print out `$row["email"]`. Then print out `$obj`. Also, include should not really be invoked in the look, it should be outside of the loop.

Comment: When printing out $row["email"] I get the correct email adresses. When echo count($obj) I get the correct number of breaches for the first email, but on the consequent emails I get 0.

Comment: With this simple debugging you ruled out MySQL as a possible source of error... Is it truly that difficult to do this on your own without any prompting?

Comment: Simply look at my answer. It should solve your problem :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Look at your loop, or better at the line before your loop. You're doing:

`$ch = curl_init();` - so you initalize a cURL session. You do this only once, since its outside of the loop.

Then, a few lines later, youre doing:

`curl_close($ch);` - you close the cURL session. You do this after every call, because its in your loop. So principally you initalize, run the cURL stuff (thats why it works for the first one) and then it stops to work, because you close your cURL session and never open a new one.

Simply take your the `curl_close$ch);` from your loop and put it at the end of your file, so you can execute all requests with the same session. Then it should work :)

Your end of the file should look something like:

```
}
curl_close($ch);
$conn->close();
?>
```

Hope it helped.

Comment: I tried adding it to the end like you suggested, but I still get the same result. It seems to still only run the first email.

Comment: Hmm. But you've removed if from inside the loop, no?

Comment: I got this to work. I had to add a delay because the API I communicate with only allows a request every 1500miliseconds. Thank you very much for your answer!

Comment: Ohh great! I was just on to write that you've nothing else to do than debugg.. posted the comment and then I thought about rate limits (got the same problem last week and was looking for over 4 hours for a solution, till i realized that there's a rate limit from 100 calls every 10 secs.)